# How to Select a substring in Oracle SQL up to a 4th char tyoe

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, trim

I am trying to find a way in oracle SQL to take all the text after the 4th "/" and count how many is match.  I need to do this in one SQL statement..

```
table name: access_log
col name: download
col name: time-stamp
value: Download file:/webdocs/data/groupXXX/case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf
```

I am trying to end up with

```
case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf
```

then a count of how many matches?  can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(DOWNLOAD, INSTR(DOWNLOAD, '/', 1, 4) + 1) AS FILENAME,
COUNT(SUBSTR(DOWNLOAD, INSTR(DOWNLOAD, '/', 1, 4) + 1)) AS DOWNLOADS
FROM ACCESS_LOG
GROUP BY SUBSTR(DOWNLOAD, INSTR(DOWNLOAD, '/', 1, 4) + 1)
ORDER BY DOWNLOADS DESC;
```

It returns this resultset:

```
|                       FILENAME | DOWNLOADS |
|--------------------------------|-----------|
| case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf |         3 |
| case/04_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf |         2 |
```

For a demo see here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddc34/8)

Comment: this is 90% right can I just add one more thing the table has a time-stamp and I need record only in 4/2011... Can you please show me how to add that and then you get the credit... thanks

Comment: add a where clause like this: `where to_char(your_timestamp,'mm/yyyy') = '04/2011'`

Comment: but I need a date range... like 4/1/2011 - 4/10/2011.. please post example... I dont know where

Comment: then this: `where trunc(your_timestamp) between to_date('4/1/2011','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('4/10/2011','mm/dd/yyyy')`. I guess `4` reffers to month

Comment: Can you edit your question so we could know what part of the `case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf` is the date?

Comment: the data is in a col called time-stamp

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT SUBSTR(download, INSTR(download, '/', 1, 4)+1)  FROM access_log
```

to get the total try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) , T1.file_name  
FROM (SELECT SUBSTR(download, INSTR(download, '/', 1, 4)+1) as file_name  
           FROM access_log) T1
GROUP BY T1.file_name  ;
```

Comment: but this gives me the right output values but I need to group them for the total

Comment: so are you looking for total records which starts with "file:/webdocs/data/groupXXX/case/" ?

Comment: no I am looking for "case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf" then the next col how many times it was access

Comment: I have edit my post. its going to show you how many times each pdf file accessed